# Embedding a Browser in a Django App

Tags: javascript, django, iframe, browser, embedded-browser

Is it possible to embed a web browser into a django web application?
I want to avoid users from being directed away from the app (ie new tabs, windows) when possible. iFrames would be perfect but because of CORS restrictions, won't work for most sites.

I imagine that an embedded browser would circumvent this issue, and given that I can secure the browser from clickjacking etc, would be a fine alternative.

I am open to any other ideas for showing third-party content in a web app too! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by embedding a browser? A browser that works within a browser will still be subject to the same CORS restrictions as the parent one.

Comment: Are you sure? Why can applications on a phone (ie, LinkedIn app) ignore these restrictions? @Selcuk

Comment: It's an app (i.e. an executable), not a web site running in a browser. If you can convince your users to download and install an executable, you can do everything on their devices.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but LinkedIn is still serving the application on its `LinkedIn.com` servers, or something along those lines. Sure, you can do everything on the users device, but why is something hosted on `LinkedIn.com` allowed to embed websites enforcing CORS?

Comment: You are confused because you think that CORS is something enforced by the server but it is not. Your browser enforces it. If you write an app/executable/browser that does not respect CORS and if you convince your users to download and install your app, you are free to do anything.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thank you. Makes a lot of sense now!